# how to estimate multi-state frailty models with comxe and coxph?

Tags: r, survival, random-effects-model, competing-risks, frailty

I aim at estimating a competing risks / multistate model with frailties with the `coxme` R-package and the `survival` package. I think that this is possible to do in the `surivial` package with the `coxph` function:

```
# competing risks model
survival::coxph(Surv(time, type) ~ X + frailty(ID), id = ID, data = data)  
# where type is a factor consisting of target states

# multistate model
survival::coxph(Surv(StartTime, EndTime, toState) ~ X, data = data, id = ID, state = fromState)
```

However, for the multistate model, it is not possible to add the `frailty(ID)` part of the formula. Why?

And: How would I go about to model competing risks and multistate models with the `coxme` package? The `surivial` package [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/survival.pdf) (p. 48) suggests that the `coxme` package superseds the method of adding a `frailty(ID)` to the `coxph` term. Hence, it would be better to model frailties with the `coxme` package. But there is no documentation for the `coxme` package for modeling competing risks or multi-state models.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm experiencing the same issue with `frailty(ID)`, whereas `cluster(ID)` runs just fine. (Though I am not confident that `cluster(ID)` is correct!)

Answer (score 2):

I cannot give you a definitive answer, but I faced a very similar problem with a multistate model.
Likewise, I could not make `frailty(ID)` work properly with `coxph`. The model took an enormous amount of time to run. It might be a technical problem, as suggested in [the 2015 paper](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/22116343/) you cite: "*Only for ordinary survival models frailties can be fitted using standard software*" (p.690).

Also, `cluster(ID)` becomes redundant if there is a univocal ID per transition (models with and without it shuold return the same estimates).

Conversely, `coxme` runs very smoothly. I think you can simply use the `coxme` package on an appropriately structured dataset (as you would with `coxph`). I found [this guided example](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/mixed-effects-cox-regression/) quite informative to begin with. `coxme` is also used in [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4964935/) to estimate a multistate model with frailty.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I think the guided example is technically not for a multistate model, as there is only one type of event (death). But the example paper is, and I think they also use a mix of functions from the survival and coxme pacakge.

Comment: Yes, the worked example is not on multistate models; it just gives a nice, practical overview on frailty models with both `coxph` and `coxme`. From my reading of the paper, the authors use both packages to run two frailty models, which are then compared. Applying the same logic used with coxph to coxme, I think you can run a command line such as: `coxme(Surv(StartTime, EndTime, toState==to) ~ X + (1 | ID), data = subset(data, fromState==from))`.

Comment: Ah, nice! Thanks for the formula. I did not know you could do it like that :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experience with frailty models, so I can't speak to why a frailty term seems to be incompatible with a multi-state model.

If you are primarily interested in accounting for intra-individual correlations and aren't wedded to the particulars of frailty modeling, however, then you can accomplish something similar with a `cluster(id)` term instead. With the `cluster` approach, the initial analysis is done without regard to the `id` values, but error estimates take the within-individual correlations into account. The idea is that a frailty term is like using a mixed model, while a cluster term is like using a [generalized estimating equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_estimating_equation).

Comment: Thank you! I believe that the 'coxph' function already takes within-individual correlations into account when the argument 'id' has a value. So I guess the 'cluster(id)' term then becomes obsolete. 
I am still wondering why a frailty value for each id cannot be estimated (such as with 'frailty(ID)'). Is it a technical / implementation issue or a statistical one (also see [this](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/22116343/) article).